# "Link to a Document" Content Type on non-English SharePoint

Tags: content-type, object-model

I'm following the code at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cliffgreen/2008/06/23/creating-a-link-to-a-document-item-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-programmatically/, and I'm worried about the line:

```
item["Content Type"] = "Link to a Document";
```

Does the value here need to be localized to the language of the SharePoint installation?  I can't find any documentation either way (or much documentation relevant to this code at all), and I've been burned by too many SharePoint localization problems before (e.g. [Is stsadm output guaranteed to be XML?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/is-stsadm-output-guaranteed-to-be-xml)) to assume it will work.  But at the same time, I don't have a non-English system to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the localized Content Type Name with [SPUtility.GetLocalizedString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms460736(v%3Doffice.14))

However make it simple for yourself and just refer to content type ID.

item["ContentTypeId"] = ID;

The below page lists all of the Content Type ID's for out of box content types.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms452896(v%3Doffice.14)